Friction and normal reaction from a wall
This question follows this recent question by someone, where, by applying a constant horizontal force on a rigid block to slide over a horizontal rough surface, it finally gets anchored to a vertical smooth wall so that there is no more relative motion. But if you keep pushing with the same force, will there be any friction at all (and only normal reaction from wall) or any normal reaction from wall (and no friction) or both? If both, which one comes to play first, friction or normal reaction? How can we derive the relation between the friction and normal reaction from wall, in the final case?
I have deduced upto this: if normal force comes to play first, there should persist zero friction. If friction comes to play first, if the same force is applied that can overcome the limiting static friction leading to apparent movement before hitting wall, then obviously there exists a normal reaction from wall (else not).
I have arrived at a conclusion that $F=N+f$. But to proceed further I need to but don't know the things mentioned above.

The answer to this question would depend on exactly how many assumptions/idealizations we make about the system. If we consider the system as deformable, then there will be static friction preventing the further left from collapsing due to the force.

@agaminon what assumptions did you mean? Rigidity? The body and wall and surface all are rigid. There is friction between only ground and object.

Ask yourself, if the surface was frictionless, would the block move?

@BioPhysicist Do you agree with Dale's answer?

Gotta that pure rigidity is pointless, but it shall really help at present. Could it be answered what comes first, friction or normal ground reaction (friction as in real life, right?)? Is there any portion which you would skip for real life conditions, but not for this hypothetical condition, so that I can calculate?

@BobD          Why, the object would not move even in absence of friction, the hypothetical case I commented in your answer. Because there is a wall. Hence I find this harder than real life one, and didn't understand the 100% of what you mean. One more thing, the applied force initially before touching can slide it over the ground.

As with my answer to the previous question, this system is statically indeterminate. That means that only applying Newton’s laws leads to a system of equations with multiple solutions.
To solve a statically indeterminate scenario requires knowledge of the stress in the material. Usually this is determined by measuring or calculating the strain and using the material’s modulus of elasticity or stress-strain curve.
Assuming rigidity prevents you from solving a statically indeterminate system.

I understood what you said. Suppose it can benefit me as I still can't understand the simple-made scenario that well. Like in the hypothetical case, the object is perfectly fitted at the corner. How shall the change in force happen? I mentioned same details in the other answer.     However, do we still need knowledge of stress, if I give the override for convenience that the object is perfectly rigid?

@Swls All you can say is that the sum of the normal force and the friction force will equal that of the external force.  It's like you've been given x+y-7=0, and told to find the value of x.  You simply cannot, because there aren't enough equations for the number of unknowns.  The best you can get is (x+y)=7.  To get any further, you need to step away from the "convenience" of the object being perfectly rigid, because that convenience is actually a hinderance.

To add to Dale's answer, one of the interesting challenges that arise when teaching introductory physics is that you typically simplify the physics so much that you can create really strange indeterminate situations.  In this case, in the horizontal direction, you have two unknown force: the normal force from the wall, and the friction force.  And you know that $F_{ext} + F_{wall} + F_{friction} = 0$.  That's two unknowns and one equation.  There's an infinite range of possible answers that satisfy these equations.
At the introductory level, there's not much to be done.  The physics has been simplified enough that such problems no longer have a single solution -- they have many.  We typically try to construct physics problems where this isn't the case, but it looks like you were handed one of the corner cases where the rules don't work well.
In reality, nothing is perfectly rigid. Nothing.  Everything deforms, even ridiculously hard things like diamonds.  It may be a tiny deformation (nanometers), but it happens.  This means there's some much more interesting behaviors going on inside the block than mere rigidity.  As Dale mentions, there's stresses and strains and a host of higher order effects which give engineers fits.  Those little internal details will result in some balance, although we don't have enough details to know what.
Another detail that will matter is how the force is applied.  At the introductory level, that doesn't matter at all.  But in practice, it matters greatly.  A sudden shock can often result in the underlying physics of the friction (interactions between the rough surfaces) to temporarially be dynamic.  In such a case, the wall is likely to take nearly the full brunt of the force.

However, in hypothetical case, can I consider negligible values as zero? However, since this is so true, I am trying to focus a bit on the theory as well. Since you said, are the unknown values of compressibility, suddenness, and others Idk yet. But there's a new idea, I got, wrote as comment to BobD... that I said with respect to real life only.


But if you keep pushing with the same force, will there be any
friction at all (and only normal reaction from wall) or any normal
reaction from wall (and no friction) or both?

As long as the applied force is present, there shouldn't be any friction force present. But after the block comes to a stop and the applied force is removed, friction will be present if the block (or wall) is deformable.
In your post you described the block as a rigid body. Consider the following scenarios where the block is a rigid body vs it being a deformable (elastic) body. (For simplicity, the wall will be considered rigid)
SCENARIO 1: BLOCK IS A RIDID BODY
Once the block comes to a stop, any further relative motion between the block and supporting surface becomes impossible. That's because any further relative motion would require deformation of either the block or wall. Since static friction only exists to oppose the onset of relative motion between surfaces, and kinetic friction only exists to oppose relative motion between surfaces that is already underway, the implication is no friction force will exist once the block stops. To look at it another way, consider what happens to the block if the applied force is removed after the block stops.
First, the normal force exerted by the wall on the block would cease to exist, since the normal force was purely a "reaction" force as a consequence of the applied horizontal force.
Second, since static friction is also a "reaction" type force, if the wall no longer exerts a force on the block, there is no force for static friction force to oppose (react to).
SCENARIO 2: BLOCK IS A DEFORMABLE BODY
Refer to the figures below where the block is a deformable (elastic) body modeled as the combination of a mass and ideal spring.
In FIG 1 the applied force is assumed to exceed the maximum possible static friction force of $\mu_{s}mg$, so it is sliding towards the left against the kinetic friction force between the block and surface. Once it makes contact with the wall, the block starts to compresses elastically until the point is reached where the spring restoring force equals the applied force and the block comes to a stop as shown in FIG 2. Once the block comes to a stop the kinetic friction force disappears. Moreover, since the restoring force equals the applied force, there is no net force that can cause motion. Thus as as long as the applied force remains, no static friction should exist.
Now consider what happens when the applied force is removed as shown in the free body diagrams of FIGs 3A and 3B.  Unlike SCENARIO 1 where the wall reaction force disappeared, the wall reaction force now consists of the restoring force of the spring. There are now two possible outcomes.
If the spring restoring force is less than the maximum possible static friction force of $\mu_{s}mg$ as indicated in FIG 3A, static friction will match the restoring force and prevent motion of the block.
On the other hand, if the restoring force exceeds the maximum possible static friction force as shown in FIG 3B, the block will slide and friction becomes kinetic. Once the restoring force, which is now a variable, falls below the kinetic friction force, which is generally considered constant, the block will decelerate with the kinetic friction force eventually bringing it to a stop.
Hope this helps.


In your first statement you said there wouldn't any friction present. Why what about kinetic friction?

@damnOk I’m referring to when the block comes to a stop.

I said the following but got deleted. Am I right to say that: (note that I am taking 2 successive steps as 2 cases, before stop and and after stop) Before it hits, the wall, it was moving with a constant velocity, because the force applied was >= the friction of surface. Then the friction acting was the kinetic friction. Now after it touches the wall, it comes to rest, and during the same time, the friction acting reduces to zero. Since we keep up the applied force, not only the friction reduces, but in the same course, the wall reaction increases from zero to max.

Suppose you release it. Then reapply it. In real life: I believe, the friction starts to act first, then after the static friction it overcome, the wall reactions arrives immediately after which the friction disappears. Why? Because: the gravity is able to keep the object adhered to the ground before applying force, while no such attractive force is able to keep the object touched with the wall already, so the wall and object are fully detached. So obviously the friction comes first here. Is this correct?

I could provide my version about real life for both rigid and non rigid objects in general, but since it is also important to look at the hypothetical case for conceptual clarity I want to know how to explain what happens if it is already in touch with the wall also. I think the actual question becomes a bit deviated from the area of rigidity.

@damnOk “Before it hits, the wall, it was moving with a constant velocity, because the force applied was >= the friction of surface. Then the friction acting was the kinetic friction.”  Your post said the applied force was constant. You didn’t say the velocity of the block was constant. But that’s OK. Let’s say it is. That would mean applied force exactly equals the opposing sliding (kinetic) friction force,  not greater than the friction force, as that would mean the block is accelerating.

“Now after it touches the wall, it comes to rest, and during the same time, the friction acting reduces to zero”.  Correct. And if the wall and block are ideal rigid bodies, the block would theoretically come to rest in zero time.

“Since we keep up the applied force, not only the friction reduces, but in the same course, the wall reaction increases from zero to max.” Yes, again in zero time if the bodies are rigid.

“Suppose you release it. Then reapply it. In real life: I believe, the friction starts to act first…”, If the bodies are rigid, I disagree. The instant the applied force becomes zero the wall reaction force becomes zero and there is no net force for static friction to oppose. Imagine if the surface was frictionless when the applied force is released. Nothing would happen. The block would remain still. Keep in mind static friction only exists in opposition to a force. A block simply sitting on a rough horizontal surface with no external horizontal force applied experiences no static friction.

“Why? Because: the gravity is able to keep the object adhered to the ground before applying force, while no such attractive force is able to keep the object touched with the wall already, so the wall and object are fully detached.” If by “adhered to the ground” you mean gravity prevents horizontal motion, that’s not true. Gravity only prevent vertical motion off the ground.

The only role played by gravity is, combined with the coefficient of static friction,  to limit the maximum possible static friction force to $\mu_{s}mg$.  Up to that point static friction matches the opposing force. For sliding friction, gravity determines the value of the kinetic friction force to be $\mu_{d}mg$ (which is generally assumed to be constant).

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
